# How do i do this using the while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l1 = ["Harry", "Soham", "Sam", "Rahul"]
for name in l1:
     if name.startswith("S"):
         print("Hello " + name + "!")
```

How do I do this using the while loop??
(name. , starts , with are without spaces.)

Comment: But why would you want to do this with while loop?

Comment: It's a question for my practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=0
l1 = ["Harry", "Soham", "Sam", "Rahul"]
while x<len(l1):
  if l1[x].startswith("S"):
    print("Hello " + l1[x] + "!")
  x+=1
```

Comment: Why use a else clause here? Just move the `x+=1` outside of the `if`

Answer (score 0):

As you will have seen there are many ways to do this. Here's another:

```
list_ = ["Harry", "Soham", "Sam", "Rahul"]

while list_:
    if (name := list_.pop(0)).startswith('S'):
        print(f'Hello {name}!')
```

**Note:**

This is destructive. In case you don't want to destroy the original list, work on a copy